# Django TemplateDoesNotExist, when trying to redirect user's

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have this structure,and basically what I want is to send the user to the right place depending on their group.

```html
myproject/
     |-- myproject
          |--urls.py
          |--settings.py
          |--views.py
     |-- pluviais/
          |--urls.py
          |--views.py
     |-- eletricistas/
          |--urls.py
          |--views.py
```

So when they login, my **settings.py** redirect to index, (**LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'**)

**myproject/urls.py**

```js
from .views import index
urlpatterns = [
                  path('', views.index, name='index'),
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
                  path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

                  path('pluviais/', include('pluviais.urls')),
                  path('eletricistas/', include('eletricistas.urls')),
                  
              ]
                                                                                           document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**myproject/views.py**

```js
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group,User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="tablet").user_set.all()
    if request.user in users_in_group:
        user_responsaveis_pluviais = User.objects.filter(username=request.user, groups__name='Responsáveis - pluviais').exists()
        user_chefes_pluviais = User.objects.filter(username=request.user, groups__name='Chefes - pluviais').exists()
        print(user_responsaveis_pluviais)
        if user_responsaveis_pluviais == True or user_chefes_pluviais==True:

            return render(request, 'intervencao')

        else:

            return render(request, 'tarefas')
```

As you can see the idea is simply depending on the groups that the users are in, they are redirected to the right place ( or go to *pluviais/* or *eletricistas/*

**pluviais/urls.py**

```js
urlpatterns = [
    path('tablet', views.intervencao, name='intervencao'),
]
```

**eletricistas/urls.py**

```js
urlpatterns = [
    path('tablet', views.tarefas, name='tarefas'),

]
```

the problem is that always giving me the error **TemplateDoesNotExist at /**, so maybe i am doing this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
def index(request):
    users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="tablet").user_set.all()
    if request.user in users_in_group:
        user_responsaveis_pluviais = User.objects.filter(username=request.user, groups__name='Responsáveis - pluviais').exists()
        user_chefes_pluviais = User.objects.filter(username=request.user, groups__name='Chefes - pluviais').exists()
        user_responsaveis_eletricistas = User.objects.filter(username=request.user, groups__name='Responsáveis - eletricistas').exists()
        print(user_responsaveis_pluviais)
        print(user_responsaveis_eletricistas)

        if user_responsaveis_pluviais == True or user_chefes_pluviais==True:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('intervencao'))
        elif user_responsaveis_eletricistas ==True:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tarefas'))      
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')
```

basically what I was needed was from **HttpResponseRedirect(reverse())**

Answer (score 0):

`render()` is a django function that takes a `request` object AND a template (HTML) path.

You need a `templates` directory in the base project, and inside that folder you need to create an HTML file.

Then, your view code could read:

```
return render(request, 'pluviais.html')
```

or

```
return render(request, 'electricistas.html')
```

Comment: I have that folder in each App , i want to send the user to the “índex” of the App

Comment: That is a piece of info missing from the OP! I would try: 

`return render(request, '/pluviais/tablet/index.html')` then, assuming you have /pluvais/templates/tablet/index.html in there.

Comment: still have **TemplateDoesNotExist at** , but i have the **index.html** there

Comment: i really dont understand why this is happen , because the template is there